# multivariate student-t regression

Tags: regression, multivariate-testing

1. I want to do a multivariate regression in R (where each output sample is a vector, instead of a number), which I know can be handled using the `lm()` function; however, the multivariate output data is not necessarily Normally distributed, so I'm trying to use the multivariate t regression as an alternative. Does that sound ok?
2. Is there a package in R to do multivariate student-t regression?

Thanks,
Golsheed